# How to animate svg path with jQuery/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, svg, svg-animate

I'd like to animate an svg's path. I know this can be achieved with `<animate>`, but the animation starts only after the element is appended to some div. So I need to find another solution, but I weren't able to find any help online.

Here is the [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/r3pboxkh/1/) so you can take a look at what I have.

**Note:** Now I'd like the svg's path to stretch the svg. So at first, it is a triangle, but it needs to smoothly convert into a square that fits the svg around it.

Thank you!

```js
// -- click the path -- //

$('path').on('click touch', function() {
  $(this).parents('svg').css({
    height: '100vh',
    width: '100vw'
  });
})
```

```css
/* -- click the path -- */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden; /* -- just for this example */
}

svg {
  -webkit-transition:
    height 350ms ease-in-out,
    width 350ms ease-in-out;
  transition:
    height 350ms ease-in-out,
    width 350ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- click the path -->

<svg fill="#000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.0" height="200" width="200" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024">
  <path d="M0 0 L405 0 L405 635"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Your fiddle does not have <animate>. If you want an <animate> solution, show us what you have so far so we can see where it differs. If you want a triangle to change to a square using SMIL you'd need to draw the triangle with an extra point e.g. a fourth vertex co-incident with one of the other 3 vertices, you could then SMIL animate all four vertices into a square.

Comment: I wish that I could just grab the path by saying `$('svg path').attr('d', 'M0 0 L1024 0 L1024 1024 L0 1024')`, I don't know how to use the `<animate>` tag, I tried, but failed. You are free to answer the question with a fiddle or pen, to show what you mean. (I also read alot about SMIL on [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/guide-svg-animations-smil/), but they just use `<animate>` as well, so same story there)

Comment: What do you mean by "but the animation starts only after the element is appended to some div"?  Why is that a problem for you?  `<animate>` lets you change the start time of an animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SMIL animations (ie. ones using `<animate>`) can be made to start on a click.

```html
<svg fill="#000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.0" height="200" width="200" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024">
  <path d="M0 0 L405 0 L405 635 L405 635">
    <animate attributeName="d" dur="350ms" to="M0 0 L405 0 L405 635 L0 635"
             begin="click" fill="freeze" />
  </path>
</svg>
```